# How to Plot graph in python using the multiple generated values?

Tags: python, database, regression, data-visualization, mean-square-error

Values of Multiple Mean Square errors is stored in MSE1, MSE2 & MSE3, as they were generated by the algorithm. 
I calculated MSE1 with 7 features, MSE2 with 6 features and MSE3 with 2 features
And I have to plot the graph between MSE and the respective features used for getting MSE but using matplotlib was little confusing .

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why was using matplotlib confusing?